# Create Highlight Cell Rule For Similar Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel Rule to highlight values in a row that are extremely similar. I want to highlight cells that have the values 20180726001501 20180726001504 since they share the same values 0015 towards the end of the number but not highlight something like 20180726001504 20180726003017.

If I wanted to create a rule for highlighting these, how would I create the function?

Comment: Can you explain the desired rule? Is it always going to be "compare the 9th to the 12th digits and if they're the same there's a match"?

Comment: is the threshold 4 digits?  do they need to be in the same place in the numbers?

Comment: Yes, all I'm concerned about are those 4 digits. If the 9th to 12th digits are the same, then highlight all cells that match. There might be multiple cells with the same 9th to 12th digits.

Comment: It seems to be in number format.

Answer (score 1):

OK updated with better understanding

```
=IF(MID(B17,9,4)="0015",1,0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understand the direction. Is there a way that would act almost like a loop? Like to highlight 20180726001501 20180726001504 and 20180726023004 20180726023024? I want to go down a long list and highlight numbers that are similar to each other.

Comment: adjust the range in the applies to section. in the format values where this formula is true section, put the topleftmost cell position in replace of B5

Comment: But this only checks if a number has 0015 in it's 9-12th position, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are in two columns (`A` and `B`) then you can use conditional formatting and the following formula:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,6),4) = LEFT(RIGHT(B2,6),4)
```

Alternative, to combine the above with learnAsWeGo's, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,6),4),B2),0)<>0
```